# How can I check which radeon driver are installed?

Tags: fedora, drivers, radeon, fglrx, amd

I am currently installing fglrx on my machine by following this tutorial https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Fglrx In the finishing touches section, it mentions that I need to blacklist any current radeon or radeonhd drivers so that fglrx will run. How can I explicitly check if such a step is needed?

My laptop has an amd E-350 processor and HD 6130m graphics card.

Comment: `grep "blacklist radeon" /etc/modprobe.d/*`. The existing ones come with the kernel.

Comment: Darn, I followed the instructions blindly and it killed my installation.

Comment: Remove the blacklist lines you added and rm the xorg.conf that aticonfig created and that should put you back to where you started.

Comment: I wish I say your comment before I reinstalled fedora. Now more importantly, how can I install the drive without fudging up my installation.

Comment: Impossible to say without diagnosing what went wrong the first time. The wiki *should* work.

Comment: It did not work for me. Although http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Fedora_18_Installation_Guide worked, even though they are just about the same.